# Contracting tensor indices in TensorFlow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

Suppose I have a tensor objects represented as `$A_{i_0 i_1 ... i_k ... i_N}$` and `$B_{j_0 j_1 ... j_p ... j_M}$` (in Tensorflow the would have shapes of N and M dimensions respectively). I want to create a contraction over dimensions **k** and **p**, so basically I want to create

```
$$A_{i_0 i_1 ... 0 ... i_N} B_{j_0 j_1 ... 0 ... j_M} + A_{i_0 i_1 ... 1 ... i_N} B_{j_0 j_1 ... 1 ... j_M} + A_{i_0 i_1 ... 2 ... i_N} B_{j_0 j_1 ... 2 ... j_M}....$$
```

What would be the right ops for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Tensorflow 11 you can use `einsum` to do that.

So assuming `A_ijkl` and `B_mnp` and supposing you want to contract `j` with `p` you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.einsum("ijkl,mnj->iklmn", A,B)
```